# Is there a better search Mysql query for Typeahead plugin?

Tags: php, mysql, search, typeahead

Technically, everything works in my code. However, I'm doing some cleaning in my UI to make sure that the user has the best possible experience. I'm using [Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) plugin that searches for an existing record. Everything works fine, except for my search query:

```
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['query']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM participants WHERE p_fname LIKE '%" . $request . "%'";
```

As you can already tell, everytime the user types into the `typeahead` input, it sends a `post` request to my php script, then runs the query and returns the result, and displays them in a dropdown suggestion. It works fine, but..

Suppose I have a participant in my record with `p_fname = "eric"`. Everytime a user types in the letter "e", all the `p_fname` that starts with letter "e" will show in the dropdown. Which is fine, but not until the user types in, say.. "erickjsgfkdfgndidf", the dropdown suggestion will still show. Because true enough, if you run the query manually, it will return the record for "eric", because of `LIKE '%eric%'`. Now I know that a user will not type in gibberish on a typical use case, but again, for the purpose of better user experience, is there a way to improve my query to make it more "strict", so to speak? Because I want my dropdown suggestion to hide when the query did not return the exact search item that a user is trying to look for.

Note: I'm aware that I can use a plugin that is more suitable to this, such as Select2, but I'm using Typeahead for a very specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to improve my query. To those who might stumble accross the same problem, you may wanna refer to [RLIKE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php).